# Applying retry on grequests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, grequests

I have a list of URLs for which I want to do a HTTP Get request using Python's `grequests` module.

Some of the URLs don't return an OK status, and in that case, I want to retry that URL.

I can do this using a Queue which stores all such URLs that have not been tried yet, or the ones that didn't return 200 in previous tries, and keep sending requests in batches. I am looking for a cleaner/more "Pythonic" implementation for this though.

I have used the `retrying` module for retries before and it is pretty neat. I'm wondering if there is some similar, concise implementation for retrying requests sent by grequests.

Answer (score 10):

You can pass in your own requests session to grequests and set retrying on that session ie.

```
    s = requests.Session()
    retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=0.2, status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504], raise_on_redirect=True,
                    raise_on_status=True)
    s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
    s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
    reqs = (grequests.get(url, session=s) for url in urls)
    for resp in grequests.imap(reqs, stream=False):
        ...
```

You can put stream=True if you want streaming.

Comment: Where is Retry and HTTPAdapter imported from?

Comment: @tim: from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

Comment: what is total count means it is 1st try + 4 retries or 1st try and 5 retries? Also how can set sleep times between each retry request?

Comment: 1 try and 5 retries. The sleep time comes from the backoff factor: {backoff factor} * (2 ^ ({number of total retries} - 1)) seconds